# How to creating a counter for (Drupal) view results?

Tags: drupal, view

How can I create a counter for my view results?

[image: this is before]

[image: this is how i need it:]

Comment: Please elaborate on your question. A counter to count what for what “view results”?

Comment: how cann i ad a picture to my comments? ist show how and what i mean!

this is before:http://picfront.de/d/83p1
and this how i want it: http://picfront.de/d/83p2

Answer (score 1):

Use [Views Custom Field](http://drupal.org/project/views_customfield), which provides a "row number" field type.